# Bootstrap 4, thead and tr don't align

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have this page with jquery, bootstrap 4 table

Here is the url
http://vault.shopshop.space/

When I hit the dropdown to select different days, my jquery will remove tbody and append some new data rows e.g. `<tr><td>...</td></tr>`

Init load (full screen good)

[image]

After select the filter (not good, thead not aligned)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append the <**tbody**> element in <**thead**>.
You should empty the <**tbody**> and then append table rows in <**tbody**>.

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>col 1</th>
        <th>col 2</th>
        <th>col 3</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <!-- Empty -->
   </tbody>
</table>
```

then append  in <**tbody**>:

```
$("tbody").append("<tr>
           <td>col 1<td><td>col 2<td><td>col 3<td>
           </tr>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely: `tbody` is under `thead`:

[image]

And as result:

[image]

You should append to the table or use `insertAfter` (http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)